# Backend admin interface with multiple web services

Tags: ecommerce, api, xml, amazon

What is the easiest way to receive data from different web services (Shopify, Amazon Marketplace Web Service, CRM applications, social media platforms, etc.) for an Internet retailer who wants to be able to see everything in one place? They basically want a dashboard that collects and displays sales and customer data to help them make business decisions. The data from each web service may need to be used in conjunction with other web service data.

Answer (score 2):

As an advice, if you're **current skills** are limited, and the project is a little too much, don't take it, there will be tons of other oportunities when you're skills have increased.

Having said so, i recommend that you invest time into any one of available php frameworks, some are incredibly easy to work with, and will make your tasks super easy.

Building a dashboard it's easy if you are using some kind of MVC framework

For a json api endpoint:

```
Class DashboardController{

public function index()
{

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($someurl));

$this->set('data', $data);



}
```

Wash rinse and repeat.... and then in your view you only put it together nicely

*Shameless Plug*: Use Quantum for this project, a nice php framework: https://github.com/carlosbarbosamexico/quantum2

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no CMS that will do this for you out of the box and will require a lot of coding using the API's provided by these selected platforms, sadly if your skills are limited in developing then you will need to find plugins or components for the CMS your using or outsource a developer who can code this for you.

You can read more at the following links (but I'm sure you know this already).

- [Amazon Market Place for Developers](http://developer.amazonservices.com/)
- [Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/)
- [Spotify](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/)
- etc, etc.

The other option and its a 'DIRTY' method is that you could iframe the pages from Amazon, Facebook and so forth, but obviously this is dirty and will not blend with the rest of the backend.

To be honest there's no shame in letting jobs go if they are out of your league, I'm more of a web designer personally and I don't kid myself what I can and can't do - I get many development jobs that I outsource, trying to make things work after taking the job that may be out of your league is sloppy and doesn't help your reputation.